# hp-ux find command not working on a list of files

Tags: find, hp-ux

We're using the following hp-ux configuration:

```
HP-UX dxp10hxw B.11.23 U 9000/800 1446354274 unlimited-user license
```

And trying to run a simple find command as follows:

```
find . ! -type l -perm -0020 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This is supposed to produce a list of all files/folders in the current directory, which have a group writable permission. However, it also lists the files which don't have a group-writable permission

We did some research and tried variations of above command like:

```
find . ! -type l -perm -g+w -exec ls -l {} \;
find . ! -type l -perm -g=w -exec ls -l {} \;
```

But nothing seem to be working. We tried googling, but not much google results for hp-ux. on hp-ux forums, the closest we could find was: http://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/commnd-to-find-All-world-writable-files-in-hpux-11-0-system/td-p/3260440 but the suggestions mentioned there don't help either.

We did try finding one file at a time. For example, if there is a file temp.txt with permissions 711 and it figures in the results when we run above command. Then we modified the command to search only for that file instead of all files in the current directory and the below command

```
find ./temp.txt ! -type l -perm -g+w -exec ls -l {} \;
```

did not yield any results. Then we tried supplying a small set of files in the folder and the list of files that was received as output was correct but as soon as the number of files increased in the folder, the results were incorrect again. So at least we realized this thing that for a big list of files (about 600 files) in a single search, find was breaking
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
find . ! -type l -perm -0020 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

is *close*.  But if you add the `-d` option to the `ls` command, it will work, by not telling it to list the *contents* of directories.

The command as given will recur through subdirectories; the question only mentions files (and folders...).  You might have meant

```
find . -type f -perm -0020 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

to ignore directories entirely.  The given command will list directories also which have group-writable permissions.

Comment: Thomas, you're the King sir!!! it worked :-)

Comment: `-type f` only includes _regular_ files. It does exclude directories and symlinks but also all the other non-regular types of files (sockets, fifo, devices...). Use `! -type d ! -type l` to exclude directories (I would still use `-d` though).

Answer (score 2):

```
find . ! -type l -perm -g=w -exec ls -lLd {} \;
```

under `/tmp` containing ~6000 files, the command above worked for me on HP-UX 11.11 server. Your problem is not coming from number of files. 600 files is only a drop in the sea, unless your physical memory amount is really low.

Comment: Hi MelBurslan, thank you, this also works :-) I wish there was option to accept two answers, since i already accepted Thomas Dickey's answer